# Using katex in angular project

Tags: angular, katex

I am trying to use [katex](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/)(a java script library) in angular 4 project,
Can somebosy please help me by telling how to use katex in angular 4 app?
I am really feeling helpless?

Comment: As it is, this question is too broad. In what way would you want angular and katex to integrate? Where does the math come from, database, templates or both? Is it embedded in text using some delimiters, or do you have math-only data fields? Do you want to render it server-side or client-side?

Comment: thanks :) I was able to integrate it with angular on client side.

Comment: What i want is : suppose i have following lines stored on the server DB.

If \( \displaystyle \frac{z_2}{z_1}\) is imaginary, 
then \(

\vert \displaystyle \frac{2z_1+3z_2}{2z_1-3z_2}\vert

 \) is

and i want the html of all these so that i don't need client side katex auto rendering.

Comment: If you have managed to do that integration, perhaps you can answer your own question to help others.